# Half-life equations

Tags: physics

> The half-life of radon-$222$ is $3.8$ days. if a sample contains $4.2$ grams, how much will remain in the sample after $15.2$ days?

I've tried solving it written out, but I keep getting the wrong answer.

Comment: You should post what you have done so far so that others can help you fix it.

Comment: Check wikipedia entry on half-life. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Half-life If you still have trouble, come here and update your question with specific details.

Answer (score 2):

**Hint:**

Use the equation $$N(t)=N_0e^{-\lambda t}$$
and $$\lambda=\frac{\ln2}{t_{\frac12}}$$
Half life time $t_{\frac12}=3.8$

$N_0=4.2$